# Copy constructor for point

Tags: c++, constructor, copy, point

Is this copy constructor correct?

```
class GPSPoint
{
   private:
      double lat, lon, h;
      char *label;

   public:
    GPSPoint (const GPSPoint &p)
    {
      if (this != &p)
      {
          lat = p.lat;
          lon = p.lon;
          h = p.h;

          if ( label != NULL )
          { 
              delete [] label;
              label = NULL;
          }

          if (p.label != NULL )
          {
              label = new char [ strlen( p.label ) + 1 ];
              strcpy ( label, p.label );
          }
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: It looks like `operator =` , not copy constructor

Comment: Use `std::string` for `label`, or if you're being barred from that for some stupid reason, write your own string class and use it; no excuses.

Answer (score 8):

If you have a pointer in your class you are probably doing something wrong.

It would be better to re-write it as:

```
class GPSPoint
{
   private:
      double      lat;
      double      lon;
      double      h;
      std::string label;

   public:
    GPSPoint (GPSPoint const& copy)
       : lat(copy.lat)
       , lon(copy.lon)
       , h(copy.h)
       , label(copy.label)
    {}
    // You should also have an assignment operator
    GPSPoint& operator=(GPSPoint copy)    // Use Copy/Swap idum.
    {                                     // Pass by value to get implicit copy
         this->swap(copy);                // Now swap
         return *this;
    }
    void swap(GPSPoint& copy) throw()
    {
        std::swap(lat,  copy.lat);
        std::swap(lon,  copy.lon);
        std::swap(h,    copy.h);
        std::swap(label,copy.label);
    }
};
```

Now that looks a lot simpler.

But hey we forgot there are compiler generated copy constructors:
So it now simplifies too:

```
class GPSPoint
{
   private:
      double      lat;
      double      lon;
      double      h;
      std::string label;
};
```

Done. The simpler the better.

If you must absolutely keep the pointer (because you think it is an optimization (its not), or you need to learn pointers (you do, but you need to learn when not to use them)).

```
class GPSPoint
{
   private:
      double      lat;
      double      lon;
      double      h;
      char*       label;

   public:
   // Don't forget the constructor and destructor should initialize label
   // Note the below code assumes that label is never NULL and always is a
   // C-string that is NULL terminated (but that each copy creates 
   // and maintains its own version)  
   GPSPoint (GPSPoint const& copy)
       : lat(copy.lat)
       , lon(copy.lon)
       , h(copy.h)
       , label(new char[strlen(copy.label)+1])
    {
       std::copy(copy.label, copy.label + strlen(label) + 1, label);
    }
    // You should also have an assignment operator
    GPSPoint& operator=(GPSPoint copy)    // Use Copy/Swap idum.
    {                                     // Pass by value to get implicit copy
         this->swap(copy);                // Now swap
         return *this;
    }
    void swap(GPSPoint& copy) throw()
    {
        std::swap(lat,  copy.lat);
        std::swap(lon,  copy.lon);
        std::swap(h,    copy.h);
        std::swap(label,copy.label);
    }
};
```

Comment: Agreed it's much simpler, however with the change to std::string the copy constructor and assignment operator became unnecessary.

Comment: +1, except the OP won't accept this, having indicated a rationale-less aversion to `std::string` elsewhere.

Comment: And what about the performance (string vs char ) if I have approx 1E6 of such points?

Comment: If you have many points and all of them have a unique label then you're not going to gain anything by avoiding `std::string`. If the labels however are indentical for many points then you could shared them, but this requires a different design.

Comment: +1. I'm impressed by the answer, it looks more like an article

Comment: @abcdef: I bet that using string has **ZERO** added cost (in fact I will bet it is faster (and uses less space)) to using a char* especially since you are already obviously copying it. Basically std::string is wrapping the work you are trying to do manually (and doing incorrectly). It already has optimizations built-in (that you are not using).

Comment: @bdonlan: Noted in the comments that you are supposed to add constructor/destructor.

Comment: @abcdef: The char may be quicker if you were trying to share labels across points (but you are not). And the extra cost of reference counting (and the ease of foing it incorrectly) will kill you first. In this case I would swap it out for a std::shared_ptr<std::string>.

Comment: @Martin: When implementing `swap()` for your class shouldn't you provide a template specialization within the `std` namespace? If it is implemented as a member function as above, will ADL still cause the compiler to call it if a standard library algorithm calls `swap()` for your class?

Comment: @Praetorian: Yes I should implement a free standing swap() for the above class. But it should just be a normal function in the same namespace as the class. The ADL (or Koenig) lookup finds the swap based on the types and looks in the same namespace as the type.

Comment: It should be `strlen(copy.label)` inside the copy-constructor body. I would have gone with the simpler (and no more dangerous) `strcpy(label, copy.label)`. BTW, this just shows how error-prone C-style strings really are and that you're better off with `std::string` 99% of the time. :-)

Comment: If there are bajillions of GPSPoints, and the labels are always short, and they are not shared with other GPSPoints, then there **might** be some performance gains to be had by using a small fixed-size character array in GPSPoint. <Insert standard disclaimer about profiling before optimizing>

Comment: @Emile: Your implementation of `std::string` might already have "small string optimization". I think Dinkumwares (used in VS) does.

Answer (score 3):

It's a bit verbose; I'd re-style it.

More importantly, it looks more like an `op=` than a copy constructor, especially because you test `label` for `NULL`ness as if it could have been used already. And, since it's not initialised, it's unlikely to be `NULL` already... `delete [] label` is then a critical error.

*But* if you made this your `op=`, then I guess that would be semantically correct.

So then don't forget your constructor (and initialise `label` to `NULL`!), copy constructor (make it use `op=`) and destructor.

---

I know you stated in your previous question (without any convincing rationale) that you "don't want to use `std::string`", but this is a perfect example of why you really should.

Answer (score 1):

In my understanding you created a valid implementation of `operator =`, not a copy constructor. 
`if (this != &p)` makes sense if the object already exists ; the same for deleting label

Answer (score 1):

In short: no.  That's not a horrible assignment operator, but it is broken as a copy constructor.

First, there is no possible way for self-assignment to occur, because you are not assigning anything.  `this` points to an uninitialized blob of memory at the start of your constructor, while `p` is a fully constructed Point object that you are copying.  The two can not coincide.  So the initial check is a waste of time.

Further down, you check to ensure `label` is not null.  As I said, `this` points to uninitialized memory... `label` can be any value at this point, there is no telling whether or not that test will pass or fail.  If it does yield not null, you are going to `delete[]` a random part of memory.  If you are lucky, this will fail immediately, but it doesn't have to.

In terms of style, prefer constructor initializer lists for initializing members.

```
GPSPoint (const GPSPoint& copy)
  : lat(copy.lat)
  , lon(copy.lon)
  , h(copy.h)
  , label(0)
 {
   if(copy.label) {
       label = new char[ strlen( copy.label ) + 1 ];
       strcpy ( label, copy.label );
   } 
 }
```

In terms of correctness, get rid of the c-string, and use a proper string class.  Then, you won't need to implement a copy constructor at all.

No matter what, if you implement a copy constructor make sure you implement a copy assignment operator and a destructor; I assume those were left out for brevity, but if not they are terribly important.

Comment: Could you, please write an operator = to see the difference? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As a1ex07 says in a comment, your code looks more like what you would put in `operator=` than in a copy constructor.

First of all, a copy constructor is initializing a brand new object. A check like `if (this != &p)` doesn't make much sense in a copy constructor; the point you are passing to the copy constructor is never going to be the object that you are initializing at that point (since it's a brand new object), so the check is always going to be `true`.

Also, doing things like `if (label != NULL)` is not going to work, because `label` is not yet initialized. This check might return `true` or `false` in random ways (depending if the uninitialized `label` is `NULL` by chance).

I would write it like this:

```
GPSPoint(const GPSPoint& p) : lat(p.lat), lon(p.lon), h(p.h) {
    if (p.label != NULL) {
        label = new char[strlen(p.label) + 1];
        strcpy(label, p.label);
    }
    else {
        label = NULL;
    }
}
```

Maybe making `label` a `std::string` instead of a C-style `char*` would be a better idea, then you could write your copy constructor purely using an initializer list:

```
class GPSPoint {
private:
    double lat, lon, h;
    std::string label;

public:
    // Copy constructor
    GPSPoint(const GPSPoint& p) : lat(p.lat), lon(p.lon), h(p.h), label(p.label) { }
}
```

Comment: Could you, please write an operator = to see the difference? Thanks.

Comment: Well, your original code in your question above is what you could put in an `operator=` just like it is.

Answer (score -1):

Yes -- I originally read it incorrectly.

However, I still suggest you use `std::string` for the label, as it will manage the memory for you and the copy constructor becomes much simpler (in fact, unnecessary for this case).

Comment: Huh? No, it was correct. You're now doing `strlen` on a NULL pointer, which is invalid.

Comment: Yes, I totally read the original code incorrectly.  Answer has been edited to remove the incorrect suggestion.